# Read ASP.NET Core logs per scope/operation

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, blazor, blazor-event-handling

Let's say I have several ASP.NET BackgroundServices and each is logging to its own scope/operation (`OP1` and `OP2`).

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService1 : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService1> _logger;

    public MyBackgroundService1(ILogger<MyBackgroundService1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var activity = new Activity("OP1");
        activity.Start();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello from MyBackgroundService1");
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService2 : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyBackgroundService2> _logger;

    public MyBackgroundService2(ILogger<MyBackgroundService2> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var activity = new Activity("OP2");
        activity.Start();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello from MyBackgroundService2");
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use Blazor and want to display a table per operation with all corresponding logs.

**Example output**

- OP1 Logs:

  - Hello from MyBackgroundService1
  - Hello from MyBackgroundService1
- OP2 Logs:

  - Hello from MyBackgroundService2
  - Hello from MyBackgroundService2

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? Especially this part `where I can see the logs per BackgroundService`
It will be better if you give an example or introduce the code repository

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you need to create a log provider that stores the information in the database and then retrieves the information from the log table.

First, create a class to store logs in the database as follows:

```
public class DBLog
{
    public int  DBLogId { get; set; }
    public string? LogLevel { get; set; }
    public string? EventName { get; set; }
    public string? Message { get; set; }
    public string? StackTrace { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }=DateTime.Now;
}
```

Now, We need to create a custom DBLogger. The DBLogger class inherits from the ILogger interface and has three methods, the most important of which is the Log method, which is actually called every time the Logger is called in the program. To read more about the other two methods, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

```
public class DBLogger:ILogger
{
    private readonly LogLevel _minLevel;
    private readonly DbLoggerProvider _loggerProvider;
    private readonly string _categoryName;

    public DBLogger(
        DbLoggerProvider loggerProvider,
        string categoryName
    )
    {
        _loggerProvider= loggerProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerProvider));
        _categoryName= categoryName;
    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return new NoopDisposable();
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return logLevel >= _minLevel;
    }

    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception exception,
        Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (formatter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formatter));
        }

        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        if (exception != null)
        {
            message = $"{message}{Environment.NewLine}{exception}";
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        var dblLogItem = new DBLog()
        {
            EventName = eventId.Name,
            LogLevel = logLevel.ToString(),
            Message = $"{_categoryName}{Environment.NewLine}{message}",
            StackTrace=exception?.StackTrace
        };
        _loggerProvider.AddLogItem(dblLogItem);
    }

  

    private class NoopDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to create a custom log provider so that an instance of the above custom database logger (DBLogger) can be created.

```
public class DbLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new();
    private readonly IList<DBLog> _currentBatch = new List<DBLog>();
    private readonly TimeSpan _interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

    private readonly BlockingCollection<DBLog> _messageQueue = new(new ConcurrentQueue<DBLog>());

    private readonly Task _outputTask;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public DbLoggerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
        _outputTask = Task.Run(ProcessLogQueue);
    }
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new DBLogger(this, categoryName);
    }
    private async Task ProcessLogQueue()
    {
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            while (_messageQueue.TryTake(out var message))
            {
                try
                {
                    _currentBatch.Add(message);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //cancellation token canceled or CompleteAdding called
                }
            }

            await SaveLogItemsAsync(_currentBatch, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            _currentBatch.Clear();

            await Task.Delay(_interval, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
    internal void AddLogItem(DBLog appLogItem)
    {
        if (!_messageQueue.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            _messageQueue.Add(appLogItem, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
    private async Task SaveLogItemsAsync(IList<DBLog> items, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!items.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            // We need a separate context for the logger to call its SaveChanges several times,
            // without using the current request's context and changing its internal state.
            var scopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                using (var newDbContext = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
                {
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        var addedEntry = newDbContext.DbLogs.Add(item);
                    }

                    await newDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
                    // ...
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            // don't throw exceptions from logger
        }
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1031:catch a more specific allowed exception type, or rethrow the exception",
        Justification = "don't throw exceptions from logger")]
    private void Stop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _messageQueue.CompleteAdding();

        try
        {
            _outputTask.Wait(_interval);
        }
        catch
        {
            // don't throw exceptions from logger
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            try
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    Stop();
                    _messageQueue.Dispose();
                    _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, it is enough to call this custom log provider (DbLoggerProvider) in the Startup.cs or Program.cs class.

```
var serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;            
loggerFactory.AddProvider(new DbLoggerProvider(serviceProvider));
```

From now on, every time we call the `_logger.LogInformation("");`, the log information will also be stored in the database.

Note: Because the number of calls to record logs in the database may be high, a concurrent queue is used to store logs.

If you like, you can refer to [my repository](https://github.com/Kamalifar/BlazorCustomILoggerProviderToSendLogToDataBase/) that implements the same method.

In order to log the areas separately(scope/operation), you can create several different DBLoggers to store the information in different tables.